# oracle correlated subquery using distinct listagg

Tags: sql, oracle11g, correlated-subquery

I have an interesting query I'm trying to figure out.  I have a view which is getting a column added to it.  This column is pivoted data coming from other tables, to form into a single row.  Now, I need to wipe out duplicate entries in this pivoted data.  Listagg is great for getting the data to a single row, but I need to make it unique.  While I know how to make it unique, I'm tripping up on the fact that correlated sub-queries only go 1 level deep.  So... not really sure how to get a distinct list of values.  I can get it to work if I don't do the distinct just fine.  Anyone out there able to work some SQL magic?

Sample data:

```
drop table test;
drop table test_widget;

create table test (id number, description Varchar2(20));

create table test_widget (widget_id number, test_fk number, widget_type varchar2(20));

insert into test values(1, 'cog');
insert into test values(2, 'wheel');
insert into test values(3, 'spring');

insert into test_widget values(1, 1, 'A');
insert into test_widget values(2, 1, 'A');
insert into test_widget values(3, 1, 'B');
insert into test_widget values(4, 1, 'A');
insert into test_widget values(5, 2, 'C');
insert into test_widget values(6, 2, 'C');
insert into test_widget values(7, 2, 'B');
insert into test_widget values(8, 3, 'A');
insert into test_widget values(9, 3, 'C');
insert into test_widget values(10, 3, 'B');
insert into test_widget values(11, 3, 'B');
insert into test_widget values(12, 3, 'A');

commit;
```

Here is an example of the query that works, but shows duplicate data:

```
SELECT A.ID
     , A.DESCRIPTION
     , (SELECT LISTAGG (WIDGET_TYPE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY WIDGET_TYPE)
          FROM TEST_WIDGET
         WHERE TEST_FK = A.ID) widget_types
  FROM TEST A
```

Here is an example of what does NOT work due to the depth of where I try to reference the ID:

```
SELECT A.ID
     , A.DESCRIPTION
     , (SELECT LISTAGG (WIDGET_TYPE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY WIDGET_TYPE)
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT WIDGET_TYPE
                  FROM TEST_WIDGET
                 WHERE TEST_FK = A.ID))
          WIDGET_TYPES
  FROM TEST A
```

Here is what I want displayed:

```
1   cog A, B
2   wheel   B, C
3   spring  A, B, C
```

If anyone knows off the top of their head, that would fantastic!  Otherwise, I can post up some sample create statements to help you with dummy data to figure out the query.

Comment: *"I can post up some sample create statements to help you with dummy data to figure out the query."* - Yeah, you should do that. :)

Comment: Ok you got me ;)  I added the sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the distinct in a subquery, which also has the join - avoiding the level issue:

```
SELECT ID
     , DESCRIPTION
     , LISTAGG (WIDGET_TYPE, ', ')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY WIDGET_TYPE) AS widget_types
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT A.ID, A.DESCRIPTION, B.WIDGET_TYPE
  FROM TEST A
  JOIN TEST_WIDGET B
  ON B.TEST_FK = A.ID
)
GROUP BY ID, DESCRIPTION
ORDER BY ID;

        ID DESCRIPTION          WIDGET_TYPES       
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 cog                  A, B                
         2 wheel                B, C                
         3 spring               A, B, C
```

Comment: This was a good idea! Thank you.  Because I didn't want to disrupt the current view with all that additional logic, I actually just built this in it's stand-alone view that contained this pivoted data.  Then in our view that needed this data, I just referenced this newly created view that already had it "pre-built".  Thanks for helping me think outside the box on this one!

Answer (score 0):

I was in a unique situation using the Pentaho reports writer and some inconsistent data.  The Pentaho writer uses Oracle to query data, but has limitations. The data pieces were unique but not classified in a consistent manner, so I created a nested listagg inside of a left join to present the data the way I wanted to:

```
             left join
            (
            select  staff_id, listagg(thisThing, ' --- '||chr(10) ) within group (order by this)  as SCHED_1  from
                            (
                            SELECT 
                            staff_id, RPT_STAFF_SHIFTS.ORGANIZATION||': '||listagg( 
                           RPT_STAFF_SHIFTS.DAYS_OF_WEEK 
                            , ',' ) within group (order by BEGIN_DATE desc) 
                            as thisThing
                           FROM "RPT_STAFF_SHIFTS" where "RPT_STAFF_SHIFTS"."END_DATE" is null
                            group by staff_id, organization)
            group by staff_id
            ) schedule_1  on schedule_1.staff_id = "RPT_STAFF"."STAFF_ID"
 where "RPT_STAFF"."STAFF_ID" ='555555'
```

This is a different approach than using the nested query, but it some situations it might work better by taking into account the level issue when developing the query and taking an extra step to fully concatenate the results.